# Clone form input with jQuery and submit to PHP

Tags: jquery, submit, form-submit, forms, jquery-clone

After the *jQuery* script successfully `clone()` the `input` elements in `form` there is a problem with submitting: the input *names* and *ids* are specified more then once.

What is the easy way to build the query from input names and values to submit the form correctly without changing the *name* and *id* tags of all inputs?

the existing *clone* and *submit* script are below:

```php
var c = 0;
$('form#products input#add_more').click(function(){
    clone = $('form#products #product_'+c);
    clone.clone().attr('id', 'product_'+(++c) ).insertAfter(clone);
    $('#product_'+c+' #unique').focus();
});

$('form#products').submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var product = 'form#products .product ';
    for (var i = 0; i < $(product).length; i++ ) {
        form = 'form#products #product_'+i+' ';
        form_submit(form);
    }
});

function form_submit(form){
            var tmp = [];
            $(form+'input[type="radio"]:checked,'+
                form+'input[type="text"],'+
                form+'input[type="search"],'+
                form+'input[type=number],'+
                form+'input[type="url"],'+
                form+'textarea,'+
                form+'select').each(function(){
                push = $(this).attr('name') + '=' + $(this).val();
                tmp.push(push);
            });
            var query = tmp.join('&');
            sql_product('insert',query); // ajax call to .php file
    }
```

Comment: So what EXACTLY is your problem and your desired effect?

Comment: Use id=your_id[], you don't need to change the ids and name multiple times.

Comment: i think adding `id=your_id[]` can't solve this because radio input types and can't see how can i build the query in this case... or maybe i miss something. please enlighten me. thy ;)